# How do I copy a web reference from one solution to another in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asmx

I'm using a RateServiceWebReference Web Reference in one solution that I downloaded from FedEx's Rate Web Service. It's a console application and I have it wired up so that everything works nicely (including the proxy class and other model class types).

What I want to do now is to copy this web reference from the console application on to my development web application.

What I've tried so far:

1. I tried copying whatever was in the web references folder over from the console app to the web app.
2. The folder icon in my solution explorer is a regular folder icon under "Web References" instead of a web reference icon.
3. I need to tell it that the folder is actually a web reference.
4. I tried adding a web reference and I put in the TEST endpoint (https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate) and it gives me an error 405 method not allowed.

I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: You should always try a service reference first. Web references use the legacy ASMX technology. There's generally no reason to use that, even if the service happens to have been created using the old technology.

Comment: I have it working as a web reference and now all I need to do is move it. I agree that I have to re-factor it at some point to be a service reference but now is not the time for that.

Comment: you should re-add it directly.

Comment: Yep, re-added the web reference to the WSDL that was hosted on my file system through IIS and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. Instead of copying the Web Reference itself, I took the WSDL, created a test website that pointed to it, and added the web reference to the new solution. It works like a charm.

Comment: While you were at that, you should have tried a service reference.

Comment: I should have perhaps. The FedEx docs make all sorts of references to adding "web references" specifically. I would hate to call them with a problem only for them to have to tell me, "Ok don't use a service reference, follow the docs and use a web reference"

Comment: Their docs were likely written before service references existed.

Comment: Amen to that. I hate web references

Comment: "created a test website that pointed to it"...how to do that?

Comment: @Nani You can use the WSDL directly with a VS tool to create the proxy classes, or you can have Visual Studio directly reference (aka point to) the ASMX itself.

Comment: Amen!, I am wondering why you didn't get any UpVote, Hail Bokambo, +1 for you